# Firefox: purge all data (cache, cookies, local storage, etc) for a specific website

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, firefox-extensions, firefox-developer-tools

Chrome has this handy tool:

[image: clear storage]

Lets you purge all kinds of storage for a specific website without ruining your experience for all other websites.

How do I do the same in Firefox?

Comment: I think you go into firefox's 'history' and choose 'forget this site'. But I can't test right now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Today) you can find the option you're looking for in the address bar. Just click on the icon beside the shield, it's usually a small lock or a sheet of paper. This opens a small context menu with the option to delete cookies and website data. (Sorry for the German screenshot)

Tested with Firefox 89 Developer Edition.

[image: Screenshot of Firefox with the described context menu open.]

Answer (score 1):

Hit F12 to pop open the developer tools menu and go to the Storage tab. You'll be able to view and delete the Cache Storage, Cookies, Indexed DB, Local Storage, and Session Storage for the domain of the page you're currently on.

Comment: how? I'm not able to right click to delete anything.

Answer (score -1):

You can clear the recent history [as described at the Mozilla support website](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-browsing-search-download-history-firefox).

Firefox has a dialog, which you can open via the Firefox menu button > *History* > *Clear Recent History...* or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.

[image: Clear Recent History dialog in Firefox]

In there you can select the time range to clear and what items to remove by clicking the arrow button besides *Details* and then click *Clear Now* to clear the history.

Comment: This offers a way to destroy all websites' info in given time window. I want to destroy one website's info without a time restriction.

Comment: I'm afraid Firefox nor the Firefox DevTools don't offer a feature to destroy only the data of one page. You may [ask for that feature in Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox&component=Developer%20Tools), Mozilla's issue tracker.

Comment: Maybe there's an addon for that?

Comment: None I know of. I searched for ['clear data'](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/search/?q=clear%2Bdata&platform=all&appver=any&page=) and ['delete data'](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/search/?q=delete%2Bdata&platform=all&appver=any&page=) on addons.mozilla.org but couldn't find an extension which only deletes all the data of a single page.

Comment: I did the same search before asking, so the question stays open.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this extention:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/clean-guru-cache-cleaner/?src=search
(Clear all storage)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: It doesn't say on the Firefox extension's page whether it can purge all data for a *specific website*.